# Pass a model property to a javascript function in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm working on Spring MVC. Have very limited knowledge in JSP...

My controller:

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("investigate");
    mv.addObject("model", Model);
    return mv;
}
```

My Model:

```
public class Model {    
public String research = "research";

public String getResearch() {
    return research;
}

public void setResearch(String research) {
    this.research = research;
}   
}
```

My view:

```
<button id="plotbtn" onclick = "myFunction(${model.research})">plot</button>
```

but it's not working. Can you point out how to correct it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button id="plotbtn" onclick = "myFunction('${model.research}')">plot</button>
```